# В каких форматах может находиться дамп базы данных на сервере?

Tags: sql, база-данных, http

Интересует вопрос, если админ не особо заботится о  безопасности своего ресурса, и, предположим, тупо кладёт дамп в такое место, доспут к которому можно получить по:

`http://domain.tld/db.sql` (например)

Интересует следующий вопрос. В каких форматах может быть дамп? Я в базах данных вообще не понимаю. Может ли дамп иметь следующие виды, доступ к которым можно получить по обычному http-запросу:

- /db.sql
- /db-dump.sql
- /db_dump.sql
- /db_dump-12_03_2008.sql
- /DB.sql
- /DB-DUMP.sql
- /DB_dump.sql
- ...

Будет ли аналогичным запрос при `/DB_dump.sql` и `/db_dump.sql`или регистр имеет значение?

Comment: Админ который не забится о безопасности **кладёт на дампы**

Comment: Если про адрес, то он может быть абсолютно каким угодно, хоть `/audio/DaTaBaSe.mp3` — он не влияет на содержимое совершенно никак. Значение регистра зависит от настроек сервера и файловой системы

Comment: @andreymal вот как?! Это не очень хорошо. Спасибо!

Comment: @andreymal в линуксе регистр всегда имеет значение

Comment: @Dillingerèmorto Это только в windows расширение файла имеет значение (и то под вопросом, оно же нужно только для автоматического распознавания содержимого). А в nix* под которыми большинство серверов это значения не имеет. я например расширение .dmp даю файлам и в именах обычно дата содержится. И кстати далеко не из всех БД дампы принято выгружать в виде sql. В большинстве для бекапов есть специализированные форматы, обычно бинарные

Comment: @dev_null тем не менее ничто не мешает использовать не линукс или сделать такой веб-сервер, который будет игнорировать регистр на любой ОС

Comment: Скорее исключение @andreymal